# Выделяются ли здесь "в частности" и "покойного теперь уже"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

К крайне интересным размышлениям подвигает(,) в частности(,) недавнее исследование(,) покойного теперь уже(,) петербургского тюрколога...
Какие запятые в скобках надо оставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**К крайне интересным размышлениям подвигает, в частности, недавнее исследование покойного теперь уже петербургского тюрколога...**

1. [**В частности**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_132) — устойчивое сочетание, используется в качестве вводного слова.
   Употребляется для подчёркивания, выделения важного элемента, для разъяснения, уточнения чего-либо в значении *именно, особенно, в том числе.*
   Выделяется запятыми (чаще всего).
2. Словосочетание "покойный теперь уже" не требует обособления запятыми (в данном контексте): *теперь* — наречие (обстоятельственное, времени), *уже* — усилительная частица.
   Затруднение здесь вызывает нестандартный порядок слов. При обычном порядке таких вопросов обычно не возникает — теперь уже покойный петербургский тюрколог.

*Десять лет назад в фильме теперь уже покойного Тенгиза Абуладзе прозвучало слово «покаяние»* (из статьи "Уроки безъязычия", 1997).

Answer (score 0):

"В частности" выделяется запятыми, "покойного теперь уже" - на усмотрение автора:  не выделяется совсем или заключается в скобки.