# Выделять ли В ЧАСТНОСТИ?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом, и(,) в частности(,) с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.
Нужны ли запятые в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Правильно:**

(1) Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом  и, **в частности**, с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.

Но в принципе можно представить другой вариант:

(2) Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом,   и **в частности** с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.

Почему он не используется? Просто в таком оформлении **нет необходимости.**

**Пояснение**

Тема вводного слова "в частности", как мне представляется, является более трудной, чем о ней принято думать. Это связано с тем, что по смыслу  **частное всегда входит в состав общего** (по принципу "в том числе"), а такие обороты обособляются (это  случай  наложения/аппликации,  повтора уже сказанного).

**Как решить такую задачу?**

Обособленное вводное слово ***в частности*** является как бы **смысловой МЕТКОЙ для частного** и в принципе справляется со своей ролью. Поэтому и **нет необходимости в постоянном обособлении этого  "частного".**

**Но  есть варианты, требующие особого внимания.**

1) Если в предложении есть слова ***в обшем/в частности***, то это наречия, которые не обособляются:

Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом на проблему **в общем и в частности** с позицией Бигиева.

2) Если "частное" по грамматике у**же является обособленным оборотом**, то ***в частности*** входит в его состав

а) **нет союза И**

Это согласуется со взглядами многих ученых,  в частности с позицией Бигиева.(При отсутствии союза И оборот становится обособленным).

б) **определительный оборот**, в том числе **с присоединительным союзом И**

Эта позиция ученого согласуется со взглядами многих, **в частности очень известных**, авторов.

Эта позиция ученого согласуется со взглядами многих, **и в частности очень известных,** авторов.

**О союзе И**

Союз И может входить в структуру предложения или быть присоединительным, для проверки нужно убрать **в частности** или убрать союз И, тогда структура предложения будет ясной.

Вот пример, где ошибается, к сожалению, Sibilla [Обособление "в частности"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432791/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Правильный вариант: "Когда его скорбь по античной эпохе, **и в частности по греческой**, утихнет, тогда он будет способен ответить на ваши вопросы".

Её поправляют, но никто на это особого внимания не обращает.

Здесь союз И — присоединительный, а оборот — обособленный определительный.

**Я просмотрела эту тему по нашему поисковику, вот  примеры с оборотами, которые уже разбирались**:

Болельщики, **и я в частности**, были в восторге. Он играл на многих инструментах, **в частности на гитаре**. Там было много политиков,  **в частности премьер-министр**. (В принципе сюда тоже можно **подставить** присоединительный союз И).

Answer (score 2):

**Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом и, в частности, с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.**

1. Выделять (запятые в скобках нужны).
   [**В частности**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_132) — устойчивое сочетание, используется в качестве вводного слова.
   Употребляется для подчёркивания, выделения важного элемента, для разъяснения, уточнения чего-либо в значении *именно, особенно, в том числе.*
   Чаще всего выделяется запятыми.
2. Запятая перед **и** не нужна: однородные **[дополнения](http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-48)** соединены одиночным союзом.
   **Согласуется** (с чем?) **с взглядом и** (с чем?) **с позицией.**

P. S. Подобный вопрос Вы недавно задавали ([Выделяются ли здесь “в частности” и “покойного теперь уже”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443261/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5)).
Ваш выбор в оценивании ответов, извините, мне показался с т р а н н ы м.

Comment: По поводу оценки ответов: я нажимаю галочку, она становится зелёной, при нажатии другой галочки (если я хочу оценить несколько ответов), зелень перескакивает на неё. И мне не понятно, какие ответы остаются оцененными.

Comment: По поводу повторного вопроса: по-моему, разнобой в ответах на эти вопросы подтверждает сложность проблемы.

Comment: Немного разъяснений. В ответе каждого участника слева есть три кружка (наведите курсор). Верхний - ответ полезен: нажимаете, выскакивает цифирка "1", участник получает +10 баллов к репутации; средний - ответ не является полезным (минус); нижний (галочка) - ответ принят - самый лучший по Вашему мнению (+15 баллов). Таким образом Вы оцениваете и поощряете тех, кто Вам помог. Полезными могут быть все ответы, а принятым только один.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь возможны разночтения из-за присутствия союза "и", делающего неяснгым позицию автора: то ли он 1) относит позицию Бигиева к традиционным взглядам, то ли 2) приводит её как пример "нетрадиционного", который тоже согласуется с чем-то ранее сказанным. В первом случае "в частности" - присоединительный союз; при отсутствии "и" он отделялся бы запятой слева - вместе с присоединяемым оборотом, при наличии же "и" и том же придаваемом смысле эта запятая не нужна::

> **Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом, в частности с позицией**
> **Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.**
>
> *Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом **[вообще] и в частности** с позицией  Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.

Во втором же случае (если по замыслу автора позиция Багиева не является частным случаем упомянутого взгляда) "в частности" оказывается вводным выражением и обособляется.

> ** Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом и, в частности, с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.

Смысл здесь другой (при всей неуклюжести его выражения) и более ясно (не одной только пунктуацией) выражается так:

> Это согласуется как с традиционным взглядом, так и (в числе прочих
> работ) с позицией Бигиева, изложенной в публикуемом труде.

Поскольку в вариантах * и ** смысл зависит от пунктуации, то  в устной форме его выявить затруднительно. Более вероятно, что автор всё-таки рассматривал позицию Бигиева как частный случай традиционного взгляда (иначе он совсем уж нескладно выражает свои мысли), тогда без "и" этот смысл будет выражен однозначно - см. самый первый вариант. У Розенталя пример такой присоединительной конструкции:

> http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=27#pp27
>
> *Новый управляющий главное внимание обращал больше всего на формальную сторону дела, **в частности** на канцелярские тонкости
> (Мамин-Сибиряк)*

Comment: В варианте 1) "в частности" не союз, а вводное слово, выступающее в роли присоединительного члена при уточнении. Не нужна ли запятая перед И в этом случае? В цитируемом фрагменте Розенталя все подобные конструкции с И в уточнении выделяются запятой.

Comment: Вводным сочетанием "в частности" является в варианте 2); в варианте же 1) это член предложения, указывающий на принадлежность частного общему. При этом, если _нет_ убирающего запятую _соединительного союза_ "и" (см. п. 5 у Розенталя), то "в частности" одновременно выполняет _присоединительную_ функцию (перед _полным_ присоединённым оборотом с ним нужна запятая; как терминологически назвать здесь сочетание "в частности" - отдельный вопрос, но это в рассматриваемом варианте _не вводная конструкция_).

Comment: При наличии же союза "и" (который нежелателен из-за возможности разночтений) сочетание "в частности" выполняет _только_ смысловую роль (указание частного по отношению к общему) и могло бы делать это, даже располагаясь после названного частного (позиция Бигиева; этому препятствует только дополнительное придаточное, ссылающееся на "Багиева"): _Это согласуется с традиционным взглядом (в целом) и с позицией Бигиева в частности_. В этом примере тоже не нужны запятые (ср. с примером с "Грамоты": http://gramota.ru/forum/redaktor/111906/#mess111910).

Comment: Ага, я понял. Вы смешали в один пункт присоединительные конструкции и противопоставление "вообще — в частности". Но ведь только в последнем случае вообще не нужны запятые. А у Вас получилось, что и для случая вводного выражения в качестве присоединительной конструкции при уточнении (Ваша ссылка на Розенталя) не нужна ни одна запятая. Если Вы согласны с тем, что я понял ответ правильно, тогда я, пожалуй, его заминусую.

Comment: Читая комменты становится грустно: я НИКОГДА не освою всех этих тонкостей со словом В ЧАСТНОСТИ (а сколько вообще правил в русском языке!!! да они ещё часто субъективны).

Comment: @grizzly 53 "Вводное выражение" имеет место только в варианте 2), где оно обособлено _двумя запятыми_, и это единственный случай, когда его можно усмотреть в предложении, причём исключительно по пунктуации (без неё смысл сказанного неясен) и при обязательном наличии союза "и". Ссылка на п. 5 Розенталя имеет отношение только к запятой перед соединительным союзом "и" и не связана с толкованиями "в частности" как вводного выражения или чего-то иного.

Comment: Да, я не смог разобраться в Вашем ответе. Возможно, я просто не могу представить себе такого контекста, когда не нужны запятые. Но я вижу, что очевидный (более распространённый и наиболее вероятный) случай, когда выделяется всё уточнение с присоединительным союзом И: "и в частности с позицией Бигиева" Вы не рассмотрели. Минусовать за это я не буду, конечно.

Comment: В первом случае "в частности" - присоединительный союз — Не союз — конструкция. Это сбивает. Но в случае присоединительной конструкции это не вводное выражение, здесь уже я ошибся.

Comment: Здесь есть сложный момент, связанный с тем, обязано ли присутствовать обобщение типа "в целом", "вообще" (при этом точно запятой не бывает), или (для исключения запятой перед "и") достаточно подразумевать эту общность, которая из контекста всегда ясна.

Comment: Да, я всегда считал, что обязано. Обратных примеров я в гугло-книгах не встретил. (Но даже если бы встретил, смотрел бы на надёжность редактуры, издания и т.п.)

Comment: Пример из предисловия к тому собрания сочинений Бакунина. "**Некоторые из этих документов неоднократно использовались историками и в частности биографами Бакунина...**" https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=Iel3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3I0hJETk3OmW6CN3drQC46ls9Zkg&w=1280